# My testFlight app is not displayed in Devices and Simulators window

Tags: ios, xcode

Excuse my poor English.

I often download testflight app container in Devices and Simulators window,
but since I upgrade my Mac OS Ventura to Sonoma, testflight app is not displayed in the window.

If I run debugging from Xcode, the app will display in the window.

If anyone knows how to solve this problem, I would appreciate it if you could let me know.

Here is my environment.
macOS : Sonoma 14.3
Xcode : 15.0
Device: iPhone13 Pro / iOS 16.0.2

I need my testflight app display in Xcode's Devices and Simulators window.